# Chaining multiple stream with rxjava2

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android, chaining

I try to write code call service API by RxJava2.

I have multiple API(included loop call API).
Here is my example code that i want.

My question is why `onComplete` haven't call?

```
Observable.just("test")
                .flatMapCompletable(new Function<String, CompletableSource>() {
                    @Override
                    public CompletableSource apply(String s) throws Exception {
                        ArrayList<Observable<Void>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                        arrayList.add(Completable.complete().delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).andThen(new Observable<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super Void> observer) {
                                Log.e("subscribeActual", "onComplete1");
                                observer.onComplete();
                            }
                        }));
                        arrayList.add(Completable.complete().delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).andThen(new Observable<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super Void> observer) {
                                Log.e("subscribeActual", "onComplete2");
                                observer.onComplete();
                            }
                        }));
                        arrayList.add(Completable.complete().delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS).andThen(new Observable<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super Void> observer) {
                                Log.e("subscribeActual", "onComplete3");
                                observer.onComplete();
                            }
                        }));
                        return Observable.merge(arrayList)
                                .toList()
                                .flatMapCompletable(new Function<List<Void>, CompletableSource>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public CompletableSource apply(List<Void> voids) throws Exception {
                                        return Completable.complete();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                })
                .andThen(new Observable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super Void> observer) {
                        Log.e("subscribeActual", "subscribeActual");
                        observer.onNext(null);
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Function<Void, ObservableSource<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<String> apply(Void aVoid) throws Exception {
                        Log.e("ObservableSource", "apply");
                        return Observable.just("Hello");
                    }
                })
                .flatMapCompletable(new Function<String, CompletableSource>() {
                    @Override
                    public CompletableSource apply(String s) throws Exception {
                        Log.e("apply", s);
                        return Completable.complete();
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.e("onComplete", "onComplete");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e("onError", "onError " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```

And result from Log is

> subscribeActual: onComplete2
>
> subscribeActual: onComplete3
>
> subscribeActual: onComplete1
>
> subscribeActual: subscribeActual
>
> ObservableSource: apply
>
> apply: Hello

I expect chaining observable end with "Void" before subscribe(Completed or `Observable<Void>`).

Comment: The `.andThen` operator that prints "subscribeActual: subscribeActual" is returning an `Observable` but that `Observable` never completes. Add `observer.onComplete()` at the end so that it completes.

Comment: The kind of code you have written is super hard to read and debug. It will make sense to break this code down. The chain is simply too long. If you are planning to use this code in production, i suggest you make it readable and modular first.

Comment: @Adi Thank for your suggestion. Could you have example for make readable or modular ?